# GLUtesselator : Issues with zero-area triangles and T-intersections

Tags: opengl, triangulation, tesselation

I came across this issue when I was trying to triangulate Text entities using GLUtesselator.  However, it can occur during triangulation of any polygon using GLUtesselator. The problem is that sometimes GLUtesselator generates zero-area triangles. Most of the times you can ignore them but there are cases where they can’t be ignored. I am trying to find a solution so that final triangulation of a given polygon do not have any zero-area triangles or T-intersections. As far as I know, GLUtesselator is one of the most robust and stable tesselator available so I would like to stick to it and won’t mind doing some post-processing to fix the triangulation rather than writing a new tesselator myself.

I will try to demonstrate the problem with tessellation of character ‘H’. Please note that I am a new user of stackflow so I can't post images yet and it is impossible to explain this problem without images so I am just posting the URL's to the blog where I have described the problem. You can also check it at GLUtesselator : Issues with zero-area triangles and T-intersections http://www.dixittech.com/blog

I think its a very fundamental problem and a solution to it will benefit lot of developers working in a similar area. I am sure I am not the first one to stumble upon it. Any suggestions how it can be done? Any alternate approach is very welcome as well.

Comment: "As far as I know, GLUtesselator is one of the most robust and stable tesselator available " Two words: citation needed.

Comment: You got me there. I can't point to specific references but that's by general understanding from various forums/articles I came across regarding this topic. The only complain I heard about GLUtesselator was that sometimes it generates zero-area triangles.